# How to get All product data from magento 1.9 database

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database

I want to gather all my product from magento 1.9 database and upload on other site of magento 1.9 any one know how to do that ? Thanks

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch information this way ..

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        ce.sku,
        ea.attribute_id,
        ea.attribute_code,
        CASE ea.backend_type
           WHEN 'varchar' THEN ce_varchar.value
           WHEN 'int' THEN ce_int.value
           WHEN 'text' THEN ce_text.value
           WHEN 'decimal' THEN ce_decimal.value
           WHEN 'datetime' THEN ce_datetime.value
           ELSE ea.backend_type
        END AS value,
        ea.is_required AS required
    FROM catalog_product_entity AS ce
    LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea 
        ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ce_varchar 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_varchar.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS ce_int 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'int'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text AS ce_text 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_text.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_text.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'text'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime AS ce_datetime 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_datetime.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_datetime.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'datetime'
    WHERE ce.sku = YOUR_SKU
  ) AS tab
  WHERE tab.value != "";
```

Comment: is image url will also be fetched? i need also product image. thanks for your reply

Comment: @SyzeDeveloper yes it show something like :`C:\wamp\www\magento\media\catalog\product\ value`

Comment: thanks bro!  I am going to run above query and export as csv then import on new site database . is it correct way ?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'YOUR_SKU' in 'where clause'
i am getting this error

Answer (score -1):

follow this article http://blog.briteskies.com/blog/recover-your-magento-catalog-from-a-mysql-dump

Dump the catalog from the first store with mysqldump and then import into second store

> mysqldump -u username -p password database_name
> catalog_category_anc_categs_index_idx
> catalog_category_anc_categs_index_tmp
> catalog_category_anc_products_index_idx
> catalog_category_anc_products_index_tmp catalog_category_entity
> catalog_category_entity_datetime catalog_category_entity_decimal
> catalog_category_entity_int catalog_category_entity_text
> catalog_category_entity_varchar catalog_category_flat_store_1
> catalog_category_flat_store_2 catalog_category_flat_store_3
> catalog_category_flat_store_4 catalog_category_flat_store_5
> catalog_category_product catalog_category_product_index
> catalog_category_product_index_enbl_idx
> catalog_category_product_index_enbl_tmp
> catalog_category_product_index_idx catalog_category_product_index_tmp
> catalog_compare_item catalog_eav_attribute
> catalog_product_bundle_option catalog_product_bundle_option_value
> catalog_product_bundle_price_index catalog_product_bundle_selection
> catalog_product_bundle_selection_price
> catalog_product_bundle_stock_index catalog_product_enabled_index
> catalog_product_entity catalog_product_entity_datetime
> catalog_product_entity_decimal catalog_product_entity_gallery
> catalog_product_entity_group_price catalog_product_entity_int
> catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
> catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value catalog_product_entity_text
> catalog_product_entity_tier_price catalog_product_entity_varchar
> catalog_product_flat_1 catalog_product_flat_2 catalog_product_flat_3
> catalog_product_index_eav catalog_product_index_eav_decimal
> catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx
> catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp catalog_product_index_eav_idx
> catalog_product_index_eav_tmp catalog_product_index_group_price
> catalog_product_index_price catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp
> catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp
> catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp
> catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp
> catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp
> catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp
> catalog_product_index_price_final_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp catalog_product_index_price_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp
> catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx
> catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp catalog_product_index_price_tmp
> catalog_product_index_tier_price catalog_product_index_website
> catalog_product_link catalog_product_link_attribute
> catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal
> catalog_product_link_attribute_int
> catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar catalog_product_link_type
> catalog_product_option catalog_product_option_price
> catalog_product_option_title catalog_product_option_type_price
> catalog_product_option_type_title catalog_product_option_type_value
> catalog_product_relation catalog_product_super_attribute
> catalog_product_super_attribute_label
> catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing catalog_product_super_link
> catalog_product_website cataloginventory_stock
> cataloginventory_stock_item cataloginventory_stock_status
> cataloginventory_stock_status_idx cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp
> catalogrule catalogrule_affected_product catalogrule_customer_group
> catalogrule_group_website catalogrule_product
> catalogrule_product_price catalogrule_website catalogsearch_fulltext
> catalogsearch_query catalogsearch_report catalogsearch_result >
> catalog_export2.sql

Comment: will it delete all products of my previous store ?

Comment: No. It went delete anything